# Django manage.py : Is it possible to pass command line argument (for unit testing)

Tags: django, django-testing, django-manage.py

Is it possible to pass command line arguments to Django's `manage.py` script, specifically for unit tests? i.e. if I do something like

```
manage.py test myapp -a do_this
```

Can I receive the value `do_this` in the `setUp` function of unit test?

**P.S.** @Martin asked the justification for using command line args in tests:

- Some extensive tests take a lot of time and don't need to be run before every commit. I want to make them optional.
- Occasional debug messages printed by my test cases should be optional
- Sometimes I just want the tests to go crazy and try a lot more permutations of data.

All the above would be quite convenient with command line options. Once in a while testing can be a lot more extensive or verbose, otherwise it'll be quick.

Comment: Regardless of yes or no, wouldn't it make more sense to add the arguments to the unit test itself? That's really one of the main use cases of a unit test - checking different edge cases etc. If you define different test functions for each case, you'll be able to call them separately like `manage.py test myapp.mytestcase`

Comment: @Martin Fair point. I've elaborated my thoughts in the answer (P.S.)

Comment: ok, then I would create functions like `testBasic`, `testCrazy` etc. and run whatever test you need on commit. I completely agree that running a whole test suite of a big project on every commit can be annoying - that's why you should create a new test for a commit or just pick the test that the commit is related to.

Comment: @user4150760 -   "manage.py test myapp.mytestcase" isn't enough for me. Sometimes I want to test on a specific client-id.  Then what?

Answer (score 11):

I just ran into this problem myself, and I wanted to avoid setting environmental variables on the command line. Environmental variables certainly work, but it's difficult to keep track of which variables have an effect and there's no error message to let you know if you've mistyped one of them.

To get around this I've used `argparse` to extract extra parameters to the command-line argument. For example, my `manage.py` file now looks something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import argparse


if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")

    argv = sys.argv
    cmd = argv[1] if len(argv) > 1 else None
    if cmd in ['test']:  # limit the extra arguments to certain commands
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
        parser.add_argument('--foo', default='bar')
        args, argv = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
        # We can save the argument as an environmental variable, in
        # which case it's to retrieve from within `project.settings`,
        os.environ['FOO'] = args.foo
        # or we can save the variable to settings directly if it
        # won't otherwise be overridden.
        from django.conf import settings
        settings.foo = args.foo

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    # parse_known_args strips the extra arguments from argv,
    # so we can safely pass it to Django.
    execute_from_command_line(argv)
```

`argparse` is a really nice library with lots of features. There's a good [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html) on it in the Python docs.

Answer (score 10):

i'm using environment variables workaround in my project (works in unix-like shells only)

```
berry$ myvar=myval ./manage.py test
```

in your module read this value using

```
os.environ.get('myvar')
```

Answer (score 7):

Django allows adding custom commandline options from the testrunner class. You can create a subclass of the default testrunner class and add your own options, and then let django use your custom testrunner as follows.

For example, create a testrunner.py in your Django project directory, containing:

```
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner

class TestRunner(DiscoverRunner):
    def __init__(self, option=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        print("Passed option: {}".format(option))

    @classmethod
    def add_arguments(cls, parser):
        DiscoverRunner.add_arguments(parser)

        parser.add_argument('-o', '--option', help='Example option')
```

This is a testrunner that derives from the default runner (so it works just like the default), except that it tells django to add an extra commandline option (in the `add_arguments()` class method) and processes the value of this extra option in the constructor. To run with this new runner, pass its name as follows:

```
./manage.py test --testrunner=testrunner.TestRunner -o foo
```

Of course you can put this class anywhere else, as long as you pass the full import name to it on the commandline.

Note that you must use `--testrunner=foo`, you cannot use two separate arguments (`--testrunner foo`), since then the extra arguments do not work. A fix is pending: https://github.com/django/django/pull/10307

This example just prints the option value, but you'll want to pass it to your testcase somehow. I couldn't find any quick info on how to pass options to unittest testcases, but you could probably just use a global (module level) variable or class variable for this (which is not so re-entrant and elegant, but is easy and works).

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative way to `manage.py test -a do_this` you can use specific [settings file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---settings)

```
manage.py --settings=project.test_settings test
```

and define in this file whatever you want.

```
# test_setting.py
SPECIFIC_OPTION = "test"

# tests.py
from django.conf import settings
...
def setUp(self):
    if settings.SPECIFIC_OPTION:
        ....
```

If you need really dynamic options, maybe you can use `sys.argv` in `test_settings.py`, but it is a really dirty hack.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this workaround. You mention :  `you can use sys.argv in test_settings.py, but it is a really dirty hack` : Can you elaborate?

Comment: You can pass any arguments to command line: `$ manage.py --settings=test_settings test some-specific-option`, and then use something like this in `test_settings.py`: `if sys.argv[-1] == "something": # do stuff` (and you must drop this extra argument after all: `del sys.argv[-1]`)

Comment: I do not find anything hacky about this. I have a separate settings file for my CI anyway, just put another var in it. Simple is Better than Complex. :)

Answer (score 4):

Following up on @Matthijs answer, you can extend the `setup_test_environment` method similar to how the `DiscoveryRunner` handles the *debug-mode*.
It changes the value of `settings.DEBUG` which can be used in your tests by importing `django.conf.settings`. But you can also add your own settings:

```
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner

class TestRunner(DiscoverRunner):
    def __init__(self, option=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        print("Passed option: {}".format(option))
        self.option = option

    @classmethod
    def add_arguments(cls, parser):
        DiscoverRunner.add_arguments(parser)

        parser.add_argument('-o', '--option', help='Example option')

    def setup_test_environment(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestRunner, self).setup_test_environment(**kwargs)
        settings.TEST_SETTINGS = {
            'option': self.option,
        }
```

In the test you can then simply access the option via the settings

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.conf import settings


class MyTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_something(self):
        if settings.TEST_SETTINGS['option']:
            print("Do stuff")
```

Answer (score 0):

Django has a built-in mechanism for running specific tests: `tags`. Use something like this:

```
from django.test import tag

class Foo(...):

    @tag('slow')
    def test_slow_something(...):
       ...
```

Execute slow tests with:

```
./manage.py test --tag=slow
```

Read more at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/testing/tools/#topics-tagging-tests